# Most efficient way to solve problem related to 2D matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy

1. I have been given a 2D matrix(n*m order) initially all elements set to zero
2. further given several pairs like (row,col).
3. I need to add 1 to each element of the given row and each element of given col for each pair
4. In the end i need to count no. of odd elements in the 2D matrix

> ```
> Order:- N~no. of rows 
>         M~no. of cols
>         N*M <= 10^6
>         Q~no. of pairs given <=10^5
> ```

I have worked out a sol. of this

```
    import numpy as np
    n, m, q = map(int, input().split())
    arr = np.zeros((n, m))  
    for _ in range(q):  #This loop works for each pair one by one 
        x ,y = (map(int, input().split()))    #(row,col) given considering matrix indexing start from 1
        x -= 1  
        y -= 1

        if x <= n and y <= m:
            arr[x, :] += 1                       # +1 to each element of that row
            arr[:, y] += 1                       # +1 to each element of that col

    print(len(arr[arr % 2 != 0]))             #printing the no. of odd elements in the end
```

this worked perfectly when `n, m, q < 300`

but for 2nd case I get a time limit error

the problem here are as `N.M = 10^6` and `Q = 10^5`

is there any other efficient way I can implement it !!

Comment: it is not specifically needed but the question gives the input as stated above.if there is any other way around still getting the job then faster then it would be welcome

Comment: what happens if the row and columns are same? Element at location [row,col] gets Value 1 or 2 (1 because of row and another 1 because of column)

Comment: it get +1 for row and +1 for col. means finally 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without creating a 2D matrix like this:

```
N = int(input())
M = int(input())

row_count = [0] * (N + 1)
col_count = [0] * (M + 1)

q = int(input())

for _ in range(q):
    row, col = map(int, input().split())

    row_count[row] += 1
    col_count[col] += 1

odd_rows_count = 0
for row in row_count:
    if row % 2:
        odd_rows_count += 1

odd_cols_count = 0
for col in col_count:
    if col % 2:
        odd_cols_count += 1

print(
    odd_rows_count * (M - odd_cols_count)    # Odd = odd + even
    + (N - odd_rows_count) * odd_cols_count  # Odd = even + odd
)
```

Input:

```
3
4
3
1 1
1 2
1 1
```

Output:

```
5
```

---

Time Complexity:  `O(n + m + q)`

Space Complexity: `O(n + m)`

Answer (score 0):

I think to substantially accelerate the process, you need to work with a 1d array.

Assume we ravel the 2d array in `C-style order` (`row-major`). With `m` and `n` being the number of rows and columns of the matrix respectively, `x` and `y` being the indices of the selected row and column respectively.

```
arr = np.zeros(m * n)

# to add 1 to rows
arr[x * n: (x + 1) * n] += 1

# to add 1 to columns 
mask = np.arange(m) + y
arr[mask] += 1
```

At the end of the day, the number of odd elements can be counted by

```
len(np.where(mask % 2 != 0))
```